Certificate problem when trying to connect Power BI with Azure SQL via private endpoint
I have setup an Azure SQL Database which I would like to access from Power BI Desktop. When I try to connect to it via a private endpoint I get an error message saying that the given server name does not match the one in the SQL Server SSL certificate.
Some more Background information:
In Azure I setup the SQL Server, virtual network, gateway and network interface. The SQL Server is configured to deny public access and only allow access via a private endpoint. I also setup Azure VPN to connect to Azure. The SQL Server is configured with database authentification (so no AD / SSO). I am able to access the database from my desktop (mac os) using DBeaver when I set it up to ignore the server certificate.
However, when I try to use Power BI to open a connection to the same database I get an error message about encryption support: The given server name does not match the server name in the SQL Server certificate. (Original error message is German so I do not post the exact message here). The server name I use is mysqlserver.privatelink.database.windows.net with my SQL username and password.
I think all I need to do is to deactivate the certificate check. So I would like to set TrustServerCertificate to TRUE but I do not see where I can set this configuration. All guides I have found seem to follow the same configuration steps as I did. But they don't mention any further action needed to accept the certificate.

use a custom connection string

In addition to using a custom connection string... if your Power BI is sufficiently up to date that it's using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5.0 or later then there's a HostNameInCertificate property you should probably use instead of TrustServerCertificate. The former ensures that the target server identifies itself correctly, whereas the latter will accept any old X.509 certificate.

Thanks for your comments. They helped me to finally get a connection. The important point was not to use "SQL Server" as a data source but "OLE DB" where more options can be set. "SQL Server" seems to have been reduced in complexity to allow easy configuration in common cases whereas "OLE DB" offers more options. This link has helped me: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/01/22/setting-sql-server-connection-string-properties-in-power-bi-and-ssas-tabular-modern-data-sources/

If issue resolved, please post the solution to help other community members.

Based on the comments I found the solution and was able to access the DB: The important point was not to use "SQL Server" as a data source but "OLE DB" where more options can be set. "SQL Server" seems to have been reduced in complexity to allow easy configuration in common cases whereas "OLE DB" offers more options. This link has helped me: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/01/22/setting-sql-server-connection-string-properties-in-power-bi-and-ssas-tabular-modern-data-sources/
